# Is there a way to use angular to format an iframe with an external domain?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular.
I have an external table that I need to incrust inside an iframe inside my web application, but at the same time, I need to change the styles to match my web page style.
I only need that, change the font color or change the background color, I cannot change the external web.

Something like

```
<iframe
        src="//tables.org/table-a"
        frameborder="0"
      ></iframe>
```

Comment: Did you search before asking here?

Comment: Yes, but I did not find results that helped me, I saw comments from people who say that it is impossible, and other people who say that it is possible, but their answers did not help me.

Comment: Thank you!, I've seen that before, so apparently it's not possible if I want to use the iframe with an external domain.